# AFPS internal fusion drive corrupted. Looking for help for data recovery

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, apfs

The other day my iMac with MacOS X 10.14 showed a black screen with the no parking sign and reboot did not permit to start the system, it gets stuck on the end of the bar.
In recovery mode the drive is not visible and disk utility shows on the SSD of 128GB unformatted, not the 1.5 TB drive...

I managed to boot on an external drive in 10.12 and 10.13, but the APFS internal drive is still not repairable by disk utility. I tried several data recovery software like Disk Drill, which manages to show my files in the filesystem correctly, but once copied to an external drive, all the files are corrupted and unable to be open.

I wondered if the APFS is repairable.

sudo gpt -r show disk0 gives me this :

```
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  236568503      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

I am not capable to understand this, even after looking on different similar subjects on stackexchange. Is there anything to do to repair the entries here?

Thank you so much, as important data is concerned.

UPDATE :

As asked here the output of diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                      *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                 209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS                     121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                      *4.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                 209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 4T Vito             2.0 TB     disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD         650.0 MB   disk4s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5     2.0 TB     disk4s4

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                    +2.0 TB     disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s4
   1:                APFS Volume Vito APFS           22.1 GB    disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot             24.2 MB    disk5s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery            519.1 MB   disk5s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                  8.6 GB     disk5s4
```

UPDATE 2
I used Drat ([Drat on GitHub](https://github.com/jivanpal/drat)) and it gives me this final error:
(I did not post the whole output, but can do this of course, if anybody is willing to look into this)

```
- There are 11 checkpoint-mappings in this checkpoint.

Reading the Ephemeral objects used by this checkpoint ... OK.
Validating the Ephemeral objects ... FAILED.
An Ephemeral object used by this checkpoint is malformed. Going back to look at the previous checkpoint instead.
END: Handling of this case has not yet been implemented.
```

Comment: Please add the output from `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: It sounds like this was a Fusion Drive, made of an SSD and a Hard Drive, and the HDD has failed. I suspect the chances of getting data off it are almost zero. I hate to ask, but: do you not have a backup?

Comment: @Andy : I added it. Disk4 is my boot drive, which I partitioned in APFS to allow un eventual transfert by recovery software from APFS to APFS...

Comment: Thanks. Agree with @benwiggy probably a failed disk. You could maybe try to book a Genius appointment and see if they can coax anything from it, but it'll probably need to be pulled out and accessed separately. And ofc, eventually replaced if you don't want to continue working from the external 4TB boot disk.

Comment: It's also possible the cable or connector to the HD failed. But my impression is that mostly happens with laptops, not iMacs, so I agree the HD itself is more likely.

Comment: yes I understand the possibility of a physical damage. But still, the disk recovery applications like Disk Drill find my drive and my data, but fail to recover them. At least one as I cannot buy them all and the process is so slow. There must be some solution to recover the files, not ?

Comment: @hubertus Disk Drill has most likely found the catalogue entries on the disk, i.e. the list of what's on the disk, but not necessarily the data that those entries point to. On a Fusion drive, parts of the same file can be stored across both drives, making recovery very difficult. Apart from trying several different file recovery utilities (most of which will show you if they can recover something before you buy them), there's not much else you can do.